# How to disable browser's default login prompt on 401 response?

Tags: javascript

Is there ANY way to suppress the browser's login prompt on 401 response when using XmlHttpRequest.

```js
        var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
        req.open("POST", URL, true);
        req.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
        req.setRequestHeader("OData-MaxVersion", "4.0");
        req.setRequestHeader("OData-Version", "4.0");
        req.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (this.readyState == 4) {
                req.onreadystatechange = null;
                if (this.status == 200) {
                    //alert("Action called successfully");

                }else if(this.status == 401)
                {
               //
                }
               else {
                    var error = JSON.parse(this.response);
                    alert(error.Message);
                }
            }
        };
```

Answer (score 1):

If the URL looks like this:

```
http://www.example.com
```

You can pass the login credentials like this:

```
http://username:password@www.example.com/
```

Or you could try sending them in a header:

```
req.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa(username + ":" + password))
```

Comment: I dont want to send the password in the request, I am already connected but the browser show the alert of authentification

Comment: @wolfSK - If the browser is asking you to authenticate then you're not authenticated.

Comment: this is not the problem if im connected or not i want to disable the diplay of the dialog of the authentification when i recieve the error 401.
Thanks a lot :)